# Would I use closure for this?

Tags: python

How would I mimic this result

```
>>> countthesewords = wordcounter("~/mybook.txt")
>>> countthesewords['coffee']
15
```

I'm guessing that you would first need to do a def within a def,

```
#filename is wordcountingprogram

def wordcounter(filename):
    txtfile = open(filename, 'r')
    txtstr = txtfile.read()
wordcounter = txtstr ?????
```

I think I'm supposed to turn the file into a library, but how do I get it so you can call it like that?

I got it, Thank you for all who helped!

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not need a function within a function. Try using the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from the collections module.

```
from collections import Counter

def wordcounter(filename):
    with open(filename) as txtfile: # Make sure file is taken care of
        word_count = Counter(txtfile.read().split())

    return word_count
```

Comment: I think this counts all the words in the file; not the number of repetitions of a given word.

Comment: @Selcuk No, it counts the number of occurrences of each unique element in the iterator, and exposes them with a dict interface

Comment: Yes, but the question is to count the number of occurences of the word `coffee` inside a text file.

Comment: @Selcuk `txtfile.read().split()` returns a list of the words in txtfile...Counter counts the number of occurrences of each of those words

Comment: You should really re-read the question

Comment: @Selcuk Perhaps I do not understand the question. [This snippet](http://repl.it/a5P/3) demonstrates the solution to how I understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you can do is to create a `class` named `wordcounter` (uppercase Wordcounter would be more [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant) and overload the `__getitem__` method. Here is an example for you to get the idea:

```
class Wordcounter:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        self.s = f.read()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.s.count(item)

w = Wordcounter('testfile.txt')
print w['coffee']
```

Result:

```
15
```

See [Python data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for details

Comment: In order for the program to use the name wordcounter as a variable to import the text file 
`wordcounter("textfile.txt")`
and as a dictionary
`wordcounter['word']` 
how would your example work?

to result in

`>>> countthesewords = wordcountingprogram.wordcounter("~/mybook.txt")

>>> countthesewords['coffee']
15`

Comment: Oh, I see! 
so for __init__, it's basically just the wordcounter()
and for __getitem__ is x() when x = wordcounter() right?

Now i just have to figure out a way to make it search the whole word and not just how many time it appears.

Comment: `__init__` is where you create the instance and `__getitem__` is where you *parse* what is inside the square brackets.

Comment: Also, what does the .s do after the self.s because I've noticed that it doesn't work without the s.
By the way, thank you so much for helping me. making class is exactly what I'm looking for. By the way, can you put another class in the `__getitem__` to push it further?

Comment: `s` is the instance variable that holds the contents of the text file. I don't understand what you mean by "push it further"?

Comment: This is a really nice answer for teaching about `__getitem__`, but @horn's answer is really the best one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Selcuk's suggestion, use len(string) to count:

```
import re

def wordcounter(filename, word):
   txtfile = open(filename, 'r')
   text = txtfile.read()
   repetition = re.findall(word, text)
   print len(repetition)

wordcounter('file.txt', 'coffee')
```